# How to calculate limit

Tags: limits

Given sequence $a_n = n\left(\frac{1}{n^2 +1} + \frac{1}{n^2 + 3} + ... + \frac{1}{n^2 + 2n + 1}\right)$. I have to calculate its limits. Looking at the plot I guess it's 1 but I don't know how to prove it. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac n{n+1}=n\frac {n+1}{(n+1)^2}\le n\left(\frac1{n^2+1}+\ldots+\frac1{(n+1)^2}\right)\le n\frac {n+1}{n^2+1}=\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+1}$$

and now apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $n\geq1$ we have
$$a_n=n\cdot(\frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{1}{n^2+3}+...+\frac{1}{n^2+2n+1})\geq n\cdot(\frac{1}{n^2+2n+1}+\frac{1}{n^2+2n+1}+...+\frac{1}{n^2+2n+1})=\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{n}{n+1} $$
On the other hand you have
$$a_n\leq \frac{n^2+n}{n^2+1}$$
So 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+1}\Rightarrow 1\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq1\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$$

Comment: @Timbuc: Internet is slow in my place

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$n(\frac{1}{n^2+2n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2+2n+1})\leq n(\frac{1}{n^2 +1} + \frac{1}{n^2 + 3} + ... + \frac{1}{n^2 + 2n + 1}) \leq \\ \leq n(\frac{1}{n^2+1}+\cdots\frac{1}{n^2+1})$$

So:

$$\frac{n^2}{n^2+2n+1}\leq n(\frac{1}{n^2 +1} + \frac{1}{n^2 + 3} + ... + \frac{1}{n^2 + 2n + 1}) \leq \frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$$

But $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2+2n+1}=1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}=1$

So

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\frac{1}{n^2 +1} + \frac{1}{n^2 + 3} + ... + \frac{1}{n^2 + 2n + 1})=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \dots \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}<\frac{1}{n^2 +1} + \frac{1}{n^2 + 3} \dots \frac{1}{n^2 + 2n + 1}<\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^2}\dots\frac1{n^2}.$$

The limit is bracketed by 
$$\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\text{ and }\frac{n^2}{n^2}.$$